# Retrieve and save gridview in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

I have a page for searching when I write my name for example in textbox it will search and display the results in a GridView. I'm using an `EntityDataSource` with a `QueryExtender` so I didn't write any code in C#.

The problem is: in the GridView I have a hyperlink when I click it, it will go to another page, ok fine then when I return to the previous page the GridView does not show the results of the search when I was left because of the postback (update panel) it show the whole data from `EntityDataSource`.

I think I have to use session but I don't know how I can do it, I mean how I can save the GridView in session and how I can retrieve it in page_load.

Comment: Even if you save `gridview` in session, what will you do with it? Because on `postback` you cannot retrieve `datasource` of that `gridview`.

Comment: umm, what should I do? I want something to retrieve my GridView after postback, did you have any idea? I see something in ScriptManager EnableHistory but I didn't know how I can achieve it,

Comment: I'd suggest moving your databinding to your code behind. When you retrieve data, do something like: `Session["pagedata"] = yourData;` You could then do something like: `if(Session["pagedata"] != null) ...`

Comment: so I have to remove DataSourceID from GridView and play it in code behind! then in SearchButton_Click how I can do it? I read something to convert GridView to DataTable and save it to session, but I thinking how I can save last data of search into session like you say Session["pagedata"] = yourData; ?

Comment: How about setting the _Target_ attribute of the hyperlink to "_blank" so that clicking the link opens a new page and your GridView page stays open behind it. Then you don't need to worry about recreating the GridView again.

Comment: yes, I know about the target but it's not good for the user it's dificult for her, I want be the same page

Comment: @sarahkhaled Could you [change the textbox form's method property to GET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20427024/3585500) (instead of POST)? Then you'd have the textbox's search value in the page's URL when you came back.